# Pass data between WPF windows

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have some code that works in winforms, but not in WPF apparently, the code is as follows:
This is set globally:

```
Private Property avar As Object
Public main As MainWindow
Public charchoice As Char
```

And then in the Window Loaded sub, this is placed:

```
charchoice = main.charchoice
```

Thing is, the next window doesn't pick up this variable, so how can I make it recognise and use it? Thanks Guys

Nick

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused about where exactly charchoice is being defined. Could you post a little more code?

Comment: charchoice is initially declared in mainwindow.xaml.vb, globally:
Class MainWindow 
    Public charchoice As Char

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and discovered that you must create a public property in the MainWindow and pass a value to the property.

Please see this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427080/change-a-textboxs-text-value-on-a-usercontrol-from-a-window-in-wpf) from a similar question I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i got same problem when i am going to pass values between two forms.
I find its solution using a simple class and Shared property.

First I create a class named with cls_pass_val which is as under:-

```
Public Class cls_pass_val
    Private Shared var_pass_val As String = ""
    Public Shared Property Pass_val() As Char
        Get
            Return var_pass_val
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            var_pass_val = value
       End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Now at the time of assigning a value:
`cls_pass_val.Pass_val='A`'

and at the time of retrieving the value:

```
Dim var_c as Char
var_c=cls_pass_val.Pass_val
```